# Python: How to calculate scores and how to exercise a time limit?

Tags: python

I am new to programming, in fact I take a class at school and I am not very good. My assignment is to write a quiz and with every question, the person has 60 seconds to answer the question and with every right answer their score doubles. 
Please help.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Do you have any thoughts on how you might start and what you need to do? Have you written any code yet? Stack Overflow works best when questions contain code that can be corrected and improved - it's not a general "help with homework" site.

Comment: Students are always welcome here A.Pet. But you have to show that you are trying. It does not matter if you are doing it wrong or right, there is no programmer who never makes mistakes. Just do some research, try something. Come back with some precise issue.

Answer (score 0):

When displaying a question — store current time to some variable. Then after user provided answer, calculate difference between current time and the time stored at previous step. Check if it exceeds 60 seconds limit or not.